# Find files with either of multiple extensions

Tags: bash, shell

I am new to bash scripting..Below is my bash script:

Currently I am searching for files of type *.fastq and I able to get the results for it. but I need to search for *.fastq.gz files as well.

```
#! /bin/bash -l
#. /usr/share/Modules/init/bash 

  Proj_Dir=$(find $File_InputDir -name '*.fastq')

    for isolate_Dir in $Proj_Dir
    do
    /** something...

    */
```

Can I do this:

```
 Proj_Dir=$(find $File_InputDir -name '*.fastq' || find $File_InputDir -name '*.fastq.gz')
```

Any help would be appreciated. Thanks.

Comment: You can do: `find $File_InputDir \( -name '*.fastq' -o -name '*.fastq.gz' \)`

Comment: BTW, `files=$(...); for file in $files` is in general buggy. You should *really* be NUL-delimiting your output and iterating over that NUL-delimited stream (which, by nature, can't be stored in a non-array shell variable)

Comment: See [Using Find](http://mywiki.wooledge.org/UsingFind) for a general discussion of using `find` correctly/safely (in this case, meaning in a way that won't break when you have files in your results with spaces or expandable glob expressions in their names).

Comment: ...to be more clear about the above: `while IFS= read -r -d '' result <&3; do echo "Doing something with result: <${result}>"; done 3< <(find "$File_InputDir" '(' -name '*.fastq' -o -name '*.fastq.gz' ')' -print0)` (the file descriptor 3 is arbitrary -- you can pick any unused FD number; typically, anywhere between 3-253 is safe).